# How can I get all the products from the given category (incl. Subcategories)

Tags: sql

I have two tables in sql:

[image: SQL Cat]

How can I get all the products from the given category incl. Subcategories?

for example (Category 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Category = 1 or Category is Subcategory from 1;
```

What I want to get:

```
Product_ID - NAME
1  - 512GB HDD
2  - 128 SSD ABC
4  - 1TB 3.5 HDD
```

Comment: can you please explain properly.Ithink for category 1 and subgategory 1 you will get Product_ID - NAME
1  - 512GB HDD
2  - 128 SSD ABC

Comment: Category 3 is subcat. form 2 and cat 2 is subcat. form 1

Comment: @JovanaRadosevic . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a subquery like the one below

```
SELECT Product_ID, Name 
  FROM Product 
 WHERE Category = 1 
    OR Category IN ( SELECT Cat_ID
                       FROM Categories 
                      WHERE Subcategory_from is not null ) 
 ORDER BY Product_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a complete mapping from the subcategories to all their parents.  In many dialects of SQL, you can use a recursive CTE for this.

Here is one method:

```
with cte as (
      select c.cat_id as parent_id, c.cat_id
      from categories c
      union all
      select cte.parent_id, c.cat_id
      from cte join
           categories c 
           on cte.parentid = c.subcategory_from
     )
select p.*
from products p
where p.category in (select cte.cat_id
                     from cte
                     where cte.parent_id = 1
                    );
```